How to grant scope to also upload captions on YouTube
I have a Python script that uploads videos and thumbnails, following the documentation, and it works. I want to adapt it to also upload captions or subtitles. Following this gist, it seems easy:
youtube = get_authenticated_service(args)

def upload(youtube, filepath, language, video_id):
  youtube.captions().insert(
    part="snippet",
    body={
      "snippet": {
        "videoId": video_id,
        "language": language,
        "name": "Subtitles"
      }
    },
    media_body=filepath
  ).execute()

This code fails with this error:
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Insufficient Permission",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "insufficientPermissions"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}

So I try to authorize my app to have permission for subtitles. [The documentation] suggests these scopes:

Authorization
This request requires authorization with at least one of the following scopes (read more about authentication and authorization).
Scope
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner

I don't think I can grant myself status as a YouTube partner, and I don't see what SSL has to do with it.
The Google Cloud Console dashboard for my app shows no results for "scopes" when I search for it on the top bar. When I search for "OAuth", I see the pages for Enabled APIs and services and Credentials, but I don't see scopes.
How can I enable an app that already uploads videos and thumbnails to also upload subtitles?

Based on the API documentation, at least one of those scopes you listed are required:

Scope
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner

First, add them to your project. Open your OAuth consent screen and in the second page you will find the scopes. Search for youtube and you will find both scopes in there as in the following screenshot.

Then, you also need to include them in your code. For example, you'll need to change the tutorial to add these scopes to the scope argument:
def get_authenticated_service_for_subtitles(args):
  flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE,
    scope=[
     "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload",
     "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl",
     "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner",  # Optional, for channels you don't own.
    ],
    message=MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE)

As you mentioned, you don't need the youtubepartner scope if you are adding the captions to your own channel. If you add to channels that you manage, then you do need the youtubepartner scope.

Is the OAuth Consent required? I don't have it in my application and I can upload videos and thumbnails, so I would like to also upload subtitles.

As far as I know, yes. Based on this, since your application requires sensitive scopes, it would require adding a consent flow. However, if this is a single user application, you don't need to submit it to verification as per here. Quick guide on how to achieve it here.

Indeed, I confirm that these are sensitive scopes. I created a OAuth consent screen, added those scopes, ran the Python app, authenticated myself, but I get this error: Authentication successful. An error occurred: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://youtube.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/captions?part=snippet&alt=json&uploadType=multipart returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.". Details: "[{'message': 'Insufficient Permission', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'insufficientPermissions'}]">. Do you have an idea how to fix it?

@emonigma could you please provide what are you passing as scopes in this call here?  python flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, scopes). I am assuming you are using the same authentication method from that gist. Make sure to add the required scopes to this (and if you had a token stored locally already, maybe remove it prior to authenticating an generating a new one). Additionally, did you add both scopes to the consent screen, right?
